# How to get img alt tag and display under image as html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, alt

I'm currently trying to get the img alt tag from each image on a slideshow and use that as the caption to be displayed below the slide.

Is there any simple way of doing this with javascript and css?

Thank you in advance!

Here's a link to the site: http://www.alison-jackson.co.uk

**Here's my written HTML:**

```html
<div id="galleryWrapper">

  <div id="slideshowWrapper">
    <div id="slideshow">
      {.repeated section items}
        {.if clickthroughUrl}<a href="{clickthroughUrl}" {.or}<div {.end}class="slide" data-slide-id="{id}" data-slide-url="{urlId}">
        <img {@|image-meta} />
        {.if clickthroughUrl}</a>{.or}</div>{.end}
      {.end}
    </div>
    <div class="gallery-controls">
      <span class="gallery-prev"><span>Prev</span></span><span class="gallery-divider"></span><span class="gallery-next"><span>Next</span></span>
    </div>
  </div>



  <!-- <div id="simpleControls">
      <span class="wrapper"><span class="control prev-slide">prev</span> / <span class="control next-slide">next</span></span>
  </div> -->



</div>
```

**Here's the outputted HTML:**

```html
<div id="galleryWrapper">

  <div id="slideshowWrapper">
    <div id="slideshow" class="sqs-gallery-design-stacked">

      <div data-slide-url="xhpxqx84l4s2dz1sxvz24un4h9bt5h" data-slide-id="544d38fbe4b0dd27d7036a64" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_199" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="552x666" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fbe4b0dd27d7036a64/1444823277877/03-OBAMA_SMOKING_XMAS_231012_HiRes-1024x682.jpg"
        data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fbe4b0dd27d7036a64/1444823277877/03-OBAMA_SMOKING_XMAS_231012_HiRes-1024x682.jpg" class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 387px; width: 662px; height: 798px; position: relative;"
        alt="Obama Smoking 2012. C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fbe4b0dd27d7036a64/1444823277877/03-OBAMA_SMOKING_XMAS_231012_HiRes-1024x682.jpg?format=1500w" data-image-resolution="1500w">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="wte8thrzcfhfe00unh2q75vtzj7n0i" data-slide-id="544d38fce4b0dd27d7036a66" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_201" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="1024x690" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fce4b0dd27d7036a66/1444826067827/04-2002_Marilyn_wank_window_bars-1024x690.jpg"
        data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fce4b0dd27d7036a66/1444826067827/04-2002_Marilyn_wank_window_bars-1024x690.jpg" class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 126px; width: 1185px; height: 798px; position: relative;"
        alt="Marilyn Reclining C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fce4b0dd27d7036a66/1444826067827/04-2002_Marilyn_wank_window_bars-1024x690.jpg?format=2500w" data-image-resolution="2500w">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="fl83poim6cqov9t6i4qpg30jp7galt" data-slide-id="544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a70" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_203" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="682x1024" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a70/1444821495137/05-2824_001-Queen-on-looHR-682x1024.jpg"
        data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a70/1444821495137/05-2824_001-Queen-on-looHR-682x1024.jpg" class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 452px; width: 532px; height: 798px; position: relative;"
        alt="Queen on the Loo C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a70/1444821495137/05-2824_001-Queen-on-looHR-682x1024.jpg?format=1500w" data-image-resolution="1500w">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="2zrbx5dnwpzuczi0vx7ewgeqa7nhbn" data-slide-id="544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a72" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_205" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="1024x771" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a72/1444821531252/06-BRANGELINAS_ORPHANAGE_HIRES_S-1024x771.jpg"
        data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a72/1444821531252/06-BRANGELINAS_ORPHANAGE_HIRES_S-1024x771.jpg" class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 188px; width: 1060px; height: 799px; position: relative;"
        alt="Brangelinas at the Orphanage C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a72/1444821531252/06-BRANGELINAS_ORPHANAGE_HIRES_S-1024x771.jpg?format=2500w"
        data-image-resolution="2500w">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="ibzi4a7wff74lm3vdducwz4zyp1c7w" data-slide-id="544d3901e4b013df5bcd17be" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_207" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="682x1024" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d3901e4b013df5bcd17be/1444821567803/08-083-Marilyn-Back%2BJFK-682x1024.jpg" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d3901e4b013df5bcd17be/1444821567803/08-083-Marilyn-Back%2BJFK-682x1024.jpg"
        class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 452px; width: 532px; height: 798px; position: relative;" alt="Marilyn and JFK C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d3901e4b013df5bcd17be/1444821567803/08-083-Marilyn-Back%2BJFK-682x1024.jpg?format=1500w"
        data-image-resolution="1500w">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="46f2v80gmwzuxhsvuiqte3a1g87gl0" data-slide-id="544d3901e4b04e8632c63118" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_209" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="1024x682" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d3901e4b04e8632c63118/1444822864869/09_MG_4915_KANYE_BABY_HEADPHONES_MRes-1024x682.jpg"
        data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d3901e4b04e8632c63118/1444822864869/09_MG_4915_KANYE_BABY_HEADPHONES_MRes-1024x682.jpg" class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 119px; width: 1199px; height: 798px; position: relative;"
        alt="Kanye and his Baby C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d3901e4b04e8632c63118/1444822864869/09_MG_4915_KANYE_BABY_HEADPHONES_MRes-1024x682.jpg?format=2500w"
        data-image-resolution="2500w">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="y9nvmit9z4fyq553moepomk3dub6ka" data-slide-id="544d3904e4b04e8632c6311a" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded sqs-active-slide" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_211" data-type="image" style="opacity: 1; z-index: 889;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="840x571" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d3904e4b04e8632c6311a/1444821696436/10-JACKPOOL-1024x681.jpg" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d3904e4b04e8632c6311a/1444821696436/10-JACKPOOL-1024x681.jpg"
        class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 131px; width: 1174px; height: 798px; position: relative;" alt="Jack Nicholson in the Pool C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d3904e4b04e8632c6311a/1444821696436/10-JACKPOOL-1024x681.jpg?format=2500w"
        data-image-resolution="2500w" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_497">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="0xc0wmfensimmqyqhriwr7f78fh972" data-slide-id="561e3db7e4b0111ed6127992" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_213" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="1000x782" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e3db7e4b0111ed6127992/1444823271267/marilyn-undressing-for-jfk.jpg" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e3db7e4b0111ed6127992/1444823271267/marilyn-undressing-for-jfk.jpg"
        class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 208px; width: 1021px; height: 798px; position: relative;" alt="Marilyn Undressing for JFK C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e3db7e4b0111ed6127992/1444823271267/marilyn-undressing-for-jfk.jpg?format=2500w"
        data-image-resolution="2500w">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="xemwpiezb8gnz59ozhblaal2yg8q5z" data-slide-id="561e3dc8e4b0111ed61279d1" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_215" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="3179x4308" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e3dc8e4b0111ed61279d1/1444823271253/7+-+36+-+Breasts+-+Sepia_LoRes.jpg" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e3dc8e4b0111ed61279d1/1444823271253/7+-+36+-+Breasts+-+Sepia_LoRes.jpg"
        class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 424px; width: 589px; height: 798px; position: relative;" alt="Marilyn Undressing C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e3dc8e4b0111ed61279d1/1444823271253/7+-+36+-+Breasts+-+Sepia_LoRes.jpg?format=2500w"
        data-image-resolution="2500w">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="hxzcjn2dokmsl5m8q3p547s03n74xa" data-slide-id="561e3ebce4b006d31181e84c" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_217" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="2772x1845" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e3ebce4b006d31181e84c/1444823270781/Elton-colonic.jpg" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e3ebce4b006d31181e84c/1444823270781/Elton-colonic.jpg"
        class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 119px; width: 1199px; height: 798px; position: relative;" alt="Elton has Colonic C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e3ebce4b006d31181e84c/1444823270781/Elton-colonic.jpg?format=2500w"
        data-image-resolution="2500w">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="fz6fd3xi34im798puf0fvjn1z0yvgw" data-slide-id="54c2306ae4b0fe251ef9410a" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_219" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="683x1024" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/54c2306ae4b0fe251ef9410a/1444823270830/0Yz1Ak7xMMlEzJ4H6bkvw74ISAYeFtGJYJv8D8nsdfY.jpeg"
        data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/54c2306ae4b0fe251ef9410a/1444823270830/0Yz1Ak7xMMlEzJ4H6bkvw74ISAYeFtGJYJv8D8nsdfY.jpeg" class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 452px; width: 533px; height: 798px; position: relative;"
        alt="Queen at William Hill C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/54c2306ae4b0fe251ef9410a/1444823270830/0Yz1Ak7xMMlEzJ4H6bkvw74ISAYeFtGJYJv8D8nsdfY.jpeg?format=1500w"
        data-image-resolution="1500w">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="y4d6tul9hptqw68l7rbh871qrq0uun" data-slide-id="54c230b9e4b07b213a484c9c" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_221" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="1000x667" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/54c230b9e4b07b213a484c9c/1444823271255/Wills_Kate_Baby_Bath_Helicopter.jpg" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/54c230b9e4b07b213a484c9c/1444823271255/Wills_Kate_Baby_Bath_Helicopter.jpg"
        class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 120px; width: 1197px; height: 798px; position: relative;" alt="Wills, Kate and the Baby in the Bath C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/54c230b9e4b07b213a484c9c/1444823271255/Wills_Kate_Baby_Bath_Helicopter.jpg?format=2500w"
        data-image-resolution="2500w">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="2015/10/14/queen-tries-on-marigolds-c-type-archival-print" data-slide-id="561e4959e4b0f8015d9008e6" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_223" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="400x600" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e4959e4b0f8015d9008e6/1444825475506/" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e4959e4b0f8015d9008e6/1444825475506/"
        class="slide-photo loaded" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 452px; width: 532px; height: 798px; position: relative;" alt="Queen tries on Marigolds. C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e4959e4b0f8015d9008e6/1444825475506/?format=1500w"
        data-image-resolution="1500w">
      </div>

      <div data-slide-url="2015/10/14/diana-gives-the-finger-c-type-archival-print" data-slide-id="561e49e0e4b08862a349ef7b" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_225" data-type="image" style="opacity: 0; z-index: 888;">
        <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="1280x953" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e49e0e4b08862a349ef7b/1444825980193/" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e49e0e4b08862a349ef7b/1444825980193/"
        class="slide-photo" style="font-size: 0px; top: 0px; left: 182px; width: 1072px; height: 798px; position: relative;" alt="Diana gives the finger. C Type Archival Print" src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/561e49e0e4b08862a349ef7b/1444825980193/?format=2500w"
        data-image-resolution="2500w">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="gallery-controls">
      <span class="gallery-prev"><span>Prev</span></span><span class="gallery-divider"></span><span class="gallery-next"><span>Next</span></span>
    </div>
  </div>



  <!-- <div id="simpleControls">
      <span class="wrapper"><span class="control prev-slide">prev</span> / <span class="control next-slide">next</span></span>
  </div> -->



</div>
```

Comment: For this you need to use javascript

Comment: Please post the source code that you've written so far.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using simple JavaScript :

```js
var img = document.getElementById("imgGoogle");
document.getElementById('divText').innerHTML = img.alt;
```

```html
<img id="imgGoogle" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="This is Google's logo">
<div id="divText"></div>
```

To do this using jQuery, you can do :

```js
var altText = ($("#imgGoogle").attr("alt"));
$('#divText').html(altText);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="imgGoogle" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google's logo">
<div id="divText"></div>
```

**EDIT : To answer your query of multiple images, you can use `jQuery` to do this :**

```js
$.each($(".imgGoogle"), function() {
    var altText = $(this).attr('alt');
    
    $(this).next().html(altText);
});
```

```css
.divText {
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.81);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="imgGoogle" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="Google's logo">
<div class="divText"></div>
    <br>
<img class="imgGoogle" src="http://72gpf1za5iq428ekh3r7qjc1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/google.png" alt="Google's logo 2">
<div class="divText"></div>
    <br>
<img class="imgGoogle" src="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/ausday11-hp.jpg" alt="Google's logo 3">
<div class="divText"></div>
    <br>
<img class="imgGoogle" src="http://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2014/08/google-algorithm-fade-ss-1920-800x450.jpg" alt="Google's logo 4">
<div class="divText"></div>
```

**EDIT : To answer with respect to the output html you have provided :**

```js
$.each($(".slide-photo"), function() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    var altText = $(this).attr('alt');
    $(newDiv).html(altText);
    $(newDiv).attr('class','divAltText');
    $(this).after(newDiv);
});
```

```css
div.slide {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 3px #888;
    border-radius: 6px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
}

div.slide img {
    max-width: 85%;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.divAltText {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.81);
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="galleryWrapper">
    <div id="slideshowWrapper">
        <div id="slideshow" class="sqs-gallery-design-stacked">
            <div data-slide-url="xhpxqx84l4s2dz1sxvz24un4h9bt5h" data-slide-id="544d38fbe4b0dd27d7036a64" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_199" data-type="image" >
                <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="552x666" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fbe4b0dd27d7036a64/1444823277877/03-OBAMA_SMOKING_XMAS_231012_HiRes-1024x682.jpg" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fbe4b0dd27d7036a64/1444823277877/03-OBAMA_SMOKING_XMAS_231012_HiRes-1024x682.jpg" class="slide-photo"  alt="Obama Smoking 2012. C Type Archival Print" src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" data-image-resolution="1500w">
            </div>
            <div data-slide-url="wte8thrzcfhfe00unh2q75vtzj7n0i" data-slide-id="544d38fce4b0dd27d7036a66" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_201" data-type="image" >
                <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="1024x690" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fce4b0dd27d7036a66/1444826067827/04-2002_Marilyn_wank_window_bars-1024x690.jpg" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fce4b0dd27d7036a66/1444826067827/04-2002_Marilyn_wank_window_bars-1024x690.jpg" class="slide-photo" alt="Marilyn Reclining C Type Archival Print" src="http://72gpf1za5iq428ekh3r7qjc1.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/google.png" data-image-resolution="2500w">
            </div>
            <div data-slide-url="fl83poim6cqov9t6i4qpg30jp7galt" data-slide-id="544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a70" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_203" data-type="image" >
                <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="682x1024" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a70/1444821495137/05-2824_001-Queen-on-looHR-682x1024.jpg" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a70/1444821495137/05-2824_001-Queen-on-looHR-682x1024.jpg" class="slide-photo"  alt="Queen on the Loo C Type Archival Print" src="http://www.google.com/logos/2011/ausday11-hp.jpg" data-image-resolution="1500w">
            </div>
            <div data-slide-url="2zrbx5dnwpzuczi0vx7ewgeqa7nhbn" data-slide-id="544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a72" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_205" data-type="image" >
                <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="1024x771" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a72/1444821531252/06-BRANGELINAS_ORPHANAGE_HIRES_S-1024x771.jpg" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d38fee4b0dd27d7036a72/1444821531252/06-BRANGELINAS_ORPHANAGE_HIRES_S-1024x771.jpg" class="slide-photo" alt="Brangelinas at the Orphanage C Type Archival Print" src="http://searchengineland.com/figz/wp-content/seloads/2014/08/google-algorithm-fade-ss-1920-800x450.jpg" data-image-resolution="2500w">
            </div>
            <div data-slide-url="ibzi4a7wff74lm3vdducwz4zyp1c7w" data-slide-id="544d3901e4b013df5bcd17be" class="slide sqs-gallery-design-stacked-slide loaded" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1444864321837_207" data-type="image" >
                <img data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-image-dimensions="682x1024" data-image="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d3901e4b013df5bcd17be/1444821567803/08-083-Marilyn-Back%2BJFK-682x1024.jpg" data-src="http://static1.squarespace.com/static/544d37fde4b0420e8843b42e/544d38eee4b04e8632c630f6/544d3901e4b013df5bcd17be/1444821567803/08-083-Marilyn-Back%2BJFK-682x1024.jpg" class="slide-photo"  alt="Marilyn and JFK C Type Archival Print" src="http://core0.staticworld.net/images/article/2014/09/google_tunnel-100432147-primary.idge.jpg" data-image-resolution="1500w">
            </div>
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Sorry to answer with almost the exact same thing, didn't see yours until after I posted.

Comment: @Blake You have shown another way to do the same thing!! That's always good. +1

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny this is so close but my big problem is that each image in the slide is different. Is it possible to use something other than the img id to get this? Or to make it broader somehow...

Comment: @MalloryMan Yes it is possible. Let me update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @MalloryMan You're welcome. If this answer helped you, you can mark this as the answer. :)

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny I've updated my question with my source code and outputted html. I couldnt get your answer to work for some reason

Comment: @MalloryMan I've updated my answer with respect to the specific html you have provided.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
var myphotoCaption = $( "#photoid" ).attr( "alt");
$('.altHolder').append(myphotoCaption)

<img src="test.gif" alt="test gif"/>
<div class="altHolder"></div>
```

Comment: This was almost exactly the same answer as below... just with jquery instead of straight Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

**It's hard to solve your problem exactly without seeing some of your code, but I can show you some stuff below about taking a list of `<img>` elements and making captions based on the `alt=""` attribute of those images.**

**TL;DR**

- Using plain JS https://jsfiddle.net/hcp77o1a/3/
- Using jQuery https://jsfiddle.net/hcp77o1a/4/

**Plain JavaScript**

I've used jQuery for this sort of thing in the past, but I wanted to see if it was possible using plain JavaScript. I don't know your exact setup, but I imagined a gallery that houses images, with each image wrapped by a `<div>`:

```html
<div id="gallery">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/8/7685/16678214344_aef36b7a5a_n.jpg"
        alt="An illustration of two falcons">
    </div>

    <div class="image">
        <img src="https://c1.staticflickr.com/9/8635/16713817201_f5a828e2ed_n.jpg"
        alt="A hand-painted botanical print">
    </div>    

    <div class="image">    
        <img src="https://c2.staticflickr.com/4/3885/14953162645_5d99097f2b_n.jpg"
        alt="An engraved plate of Jesus College">
    </div>     
</div>
```

Then with a simple bit of JavaScript we can look at each of these images and put the contents of their `alt` attributes into `<span>` elements:

First, find our gallery container, and the list of image containers within it:

```js
var gallery = document.getElementById('gallery');
var imageContainers = gallery.getElementsByClassName('image-container');
```

Loop through the image containers, finding the `alt` attributes, creating `<span>` elements for them to live in, putting the `alt` contents into the `<span>` you've created, and finally insert that `<span>` into the image containers, alongside each image:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < imageContainers.length; i++) {
    // Find the image in each container:
    var image = imageContainers[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0];

    // Create a span element - we'll use this to house our caption:
    var caption = document.createElement('span');

    // Stick the alt tag from the image we found above into the caption <span>:
    caption.innerHTML = image.alt;

    // Insert the caption <span> into the image container:
    imageContainers[i].appendChild(caption);
}
```

Check out the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/hcp77o1a/3/ to see this in action.

**jQuery**

Using the same HTML template, this jQuery will perform the same work:

```js
// Find our gallery container, and the list of image containers within it:
var imageContainers = $('#gallery').find('.image-container');

// Loop through the image containers:
$.each(imageContainers, function (i) {

    // Find the image in each container:
    var image = $(imageContainers[i]).find('img')[0];

    // Create a span element - we'll use this to house our caption:
    var caption = document.createElement('span');

    // Stick the alt tag from the image we found above into the caption
    $(caption).html(image.alt);

    // Insert the caption <span> into the image container:
    $(imageContainers[i]).append(caption);
});
```

In action at the following fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hcp77o1a/4/

Hope that helps - let me know if not!

Comment: @MalloryMan I just updated my answer as I'd mixed up some of my jsfiddle links. Apologies if you'd visited the incorrect links already - the right ones are included in my answer above now!

Comment: thank you for this - I'll update my question with my outputted code. It looks crazy but its output from JSON data etc.